# Global keyboards events on React

Tags: reactjs, addeventlistener

I'm making a small drum machine on React, and my idea is that when I press a key on the keyboard a specific sound is played depending which key was pressed. The problem I have is that I want the onKeyPress or onKeyDown event working on window scope, because if I put the event listener on an specific component that component has to be on focus to listen the event. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a `keydown` listener on the window in the `componentDidMount` of your topmost component.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { lastPressedKey: null };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyPress);
  }

  handleKeyPress = event => {
    this.setState({ lastPressedKey: event.key });
  };

  render() {
    return <div>Key last pressed: {this.state.lastPressedKey}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do the same as [Tholle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53033698/10022881) answer example but using [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html).

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function App(){
    
  const [lastPressedKey, setLastPressedKey] = useState(null);
  
  const handleKeyPress = (event) => setLastPressedKey(event.key);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
    
    return () => window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
  }, []);

    return <div>Key last pressed: {lastPressedKey}</div>
}
```